# Twitter api returning empty body with node.js

Tags: node.js, express, twitter

I'm trying to access the twitter api to get posts from a hashtag. I followed the steps for application only authentication. Step 2 is to get a bearer token which I am able to do. However after that step, when I send a get request to get the tweets I receive an empty body.

In the following code I have omitted the API key itself.

```
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    //var sendNotification = require('./utils/sendNotification.js');
    var request = require('request');
    var app = express();

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
          extended: true
    }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());



    function getTweets(){
         request.post({
                headers: {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',"Authorization": 'Basic WmR5Tk9tMHJQUlV3VVlwZm1iRDR3eTRCeTpFdVRoZ2FPSEZpNDJsM0h6azlYWjJwaWNCaFA2SFh0RnBDdkNycDN2Zk1zM29TV2NGYw=='},
                url:     'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token',
                body: 'grant_type=client_credentials'
         }, function(error, response, body){
                var token =JSON.parse(body)['access_token'];
                console.log("Bearer "+ token);
                request.get({
                      headers: {'Authorization':'Bearer ' + JSON.stringify(token)},
                      url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?',
                      body: encodeURIComponent('q=#dubNations')
                },function(e,r,b){
                   console.log(r)
                  console.log(b)
                });
         });

   }
```

Part of the output(the response) is:

```
     ClientRequest {
    domain: null,
    _events: [Object],
    _eventsCount: 5,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    output: [],
    outputEncodings: [],
    outputCallbacks: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedHeader: [Object],
    _contentLength: null,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    socket: [Object],
    connection: [Object],
    _header: 'GET /1.1/search/tweets.json? HTTP/1.1\r\nAuthorization: Bearer "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMzZvgAAAAAATAmG%2Fj8Hnx3oqys3DqfsfbuSuIU%3DVUfy6IOBmx5QPrvhHybuLSHcG8fE8sO27r1MjX1YZ2Ar4ynwHz"\r\nhost: api.twitter.com\r\ncontent-length: 17\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
    _headers: [Object],
    _headerNames: [Object],
    _onPendingData: null,
    agent: [Object],
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/1.1/search/tweets.json?',
    _ended: true,
    parser: null,
    res: [Circular] },
 ntick: true,
 response: [Circular],
 originalHost: 'api.twitter.com',
 originalHostHeaderName: 'host',
 responseContent: [Circular],
 _ended: true,
 _callbackCalled: true },
 toJSON: [Function: responseToJSON],
 caseless: 
  Caseless {
    dict: 
     { connection: 'close',
      'content-length': '0',
    date: 'Mon, 20 Jun 2016 02:22:03 GMT',
    server: 'tsa_a',
    'x-connection-hash': '6cd802f0e295a3ad66ee45459323b83c' } },
read: [Function],
 body: '' }
```

If you need more just ask.

I'm not sure why the body is empty, since the bearer token is being returned correctly, and I'm simply doing a get request for a hashtag.

Comment: Why not append encodeURIComponent('q=#dubNations') to the URL string in your get instead of putting in body. I looked through the docs and can't verify this, but BODY on requests is normally utilized for sending info on POSTs/PUTs. Not Get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax of the GET request is wrong (as pointed out by @Brant). You should use the `qs` property:

```
request.get({
    headers: {'Authorization':'Bearer ' + JSON.stringify(token)},
    url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?',
    json: true,
    qs: {
        q: '#dubNations'
    }
},function(e,r,b){
    console.log(r)
    console.log(b)
});
```

I also added the `json: true` property as this will tell request to parse the response as JSON and return it in your `b` parameter.